# Python Regex: How do I search and pull starting from the end of the text?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of dates listed as such:

> ['2018-02-15 00:48:14 -0800', '2018-02-15 04:15:00 -0800', '2018-02-15
>   06:19:09 -0800', '2018-02-15 09:53:55 -0800', '2018-02-15 14:02:52
>   -0800']

My goal is to only get the last date, 2018-02-15 14:02:52 -0800. I tried writing `re.search(", (.*?)']", datelist)` but it returns the first date instead.

I'm a python noob, is there any way of pulling the last date only?

Comment: You should not be using regex with a list. Please read the documentation on indexing a list in Python.

Comment: All date formats seem identical. Do you want the last date in the string ? the earliest date ? how do you wish to filter this ?

Comment: get the list[-1] to retrieve from the right.

Comment: … and if this is a string instead of a real list, then parse it using `ast.literal_eval` first.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged I'm trying to get the last date string, 2018-02-15 14:02:52 -0800

Comment: If it is an actual list you're talking about, @DanielGale is right. `list[-1]` would suffice

Comment: Regarding "the documentation" on indexing a list on Python, start here:
  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists
  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html
(substituting "3" for "2" in those URLs if you're using python 3.x (which you probably should be unless you have a specific reason for sticking with 2.7)).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the program

```
#!/usr/bin/python

list = ['2018-02-15 00:48:14 -0800', '2018-02-15 04:15:00 -0800', '2018-02-15 06:19:09 -0800', '2018-02-15 09:53:55 -0800', '2018-02-15 14:02:52 -0800'];

print "Last date in list: ", list[-1]
```

reference page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm